# CSRF tokens vs Nonce confusion - are they the same?

Tags: php, csrf, nonce

In a attempt to make the current application I'm developing more secure, I've been reading about CSRF tokens and also Nonce.

My question simply is, Are CSRF tokens and Nonce the same thing? from what I could gather so far is that both these methods have different techniques to accomplish the same goal, or am I misunderstanding something?

If they are different, could you be nice enough to provide some example code or point me to some links where i can learn more about how to implementing nonces in PHP apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nonce is usually some random string that is added to request just to change in unpredictable way the data, which is used to calculate the signature. So nonce usually is not used by any server-side business logic.

While CSRF-token is stored somewhere on server, passed to the client and need to be returned back to the server to compare. And if matches - then OK.

So in your case the better will be to save csrf token once in a session variable like

```
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
```

and use it unchanged during the session life in all forms you have in your application.

(If you don't have `random_bytes()`, use [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) to polyfill it.)

Comment: hmm... i thought i read some where that people store nonce values in a database table? currently i am defining form_tokens for each new form and not just 'One' so each time a user is a form script it is passed through a csrf token, is this way of doing it alright?

Comment: @Zubair1: I think that it is overengeneering and can cause some troubles for users and developer: now you need to store a lot of tokens simultaneously, or visitors cannot post forms from different tabs... One token is not less secured, but much more handy. What about nonce - never seen that in real life, may be.

Comment: @zerkms: thanks, that's a good point, and it surely would be easier to maintain it by just assigning the csrf_token once. Should i set the csrf_token after the user has logged in successfully? and destroy that csrf_token when the user logs out? but then when should i be validating the csrf_token? at the time of form submission?

I'm also interested in Nonce too but implementing it right now seems more complicated to me since i don't quite correctly understand to engineer it into the app.

Comment: @Zubair1: Implement a function `getCsrfToken()` that returns a value when you need it and creates (stores in session) on demand, only when it is required. And don't care of deleting it. About nonce: I only know about usage nonce in APIs, not in regular interconnection scenarios with user (browser) and server.

Comment: @zerkms: sorry but i think i'm getting abit confused here, i get the part that the getToken() function should return a token. I use that token and assign it to a session var. but what i dont understand is when should i be assigning this token to the session variable? Currently i'm doing it like this, the user is on a form page, before the form is displayed a new token is generated and assigned to the session variable (a new token on each reload of the form) before the form is processed i validate the token and check if it matches the one in session. If it does everything continues else it wont

Comment: @Zubair1: `getToken()` persists the token in session and returns it. Pseudocode: `getToken() { if(there is no token in session) { generate and store to session } return token from session; }`

Comment: @zerkms: thanks for clearing that up more, but sorry again i got confused and was actually wanting to know about when should i use the token it generates? like in my current example i am validating the token before the form is being processed, should that be kept the same in this case as well? ( and should i still be passing the token in form hidden fields? if not, how i do validate it then)? thanks again ^_^

Comment: @Zubair1: 1. You put it in hidden field of each form 2. Before you process the form - you compare the `if ($_POST['csrf_token'] == getToken())`. If it is true - then everything ok.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks a million! Makes much more sense to me now :) Trying out now ^_^

Comment: -Back :) all seem to have went as expected :) but i still want to confirm if i'm doing it right: `1).Set Token when login is successful. 2).When the user is on a form hidden token is sent. 3). After submitting the form request is checked to see if the token provided matched the one assigned to the user during login, if it does the form processing continues otherwise it doesn't.` This all worked well until here i quickly came to a point where i wanted to stop double form submissions and this method was allowing it, so after the form processed i destroyed the current token and assigned a new one

Comment: sorry ran out of space to insert more words, so as i was saying i assigned a new token after the submission was a success, so that once the data is in the db the user wont be able to make double submission on accident, i would normally not worry about that here and check for duplicates while processing, but the db table i'm writting to can allow duplicate data but i dont want un-intenional duplicates such as accidentally clicking the submit button twice. So does this look ok to you? it seems to be working at the moment.

Comment: @Zubair1: 1) No. Use `getToken` regardless user registered or not, for any forms that triggers any business logic. "so after the form processed i destroyed the current token and assigned a new one" for what reason? What will you do if any visitor opens your site in 2 different tabs? *CSRF_token is not a protection against double submission*, but against **CSRF attacks**. If user will decide to post the same twice and you have no restrictions on that - he will do that, doesn't matter whether you have any kind of token in form or not.

Comment: @zerkms: Earlier before i decided to set token during login, i tried setting the token after session_start() but it wasnt persisting the token, it was generating a new one on each reload and the token being sent from hidden form field was Persisting, thus not allowing the form to be processed at all. so i added to set the token during login because no one really can access the form without actually logging in (i'm adding this feature in the admin panel).

Comment: @zerkms: i thought the CSRF tokens were also used to stop replay data? isn't that un-intentional data submission? thats also what i'm trying to prevent (where needed), this form doesnt require each rows to be filled with unique data, but that doesn't mean that i shouldn't be stopping accidental submissions (like when the user accidentally presses/clicks the submit button twice, the same data would be written twice but it isn't what the user intended to do so.

Comment: @Zubair1: to prevent double submission - just disable submit button after user clicks it. Exactly like stackoverflow.com does.

Comment: @zerkms: ok, thanks. but do you think its ok that i assign the token after the user login is successful only? i dont see any point in assigning the token to a user who isnt logged in since there is no way for that user to manipulate any data inside the secured area.

Comment: @Zubair1: if that solves your issues - then yes. In my projects I never think about it, I generate token by demant, regardless user authorization.

Answer (score 24):

No, they're not the same.

Nonces prevent replay attacks (prevent eavesdropper from storing signed request and re-submitting it later, e.g. if Alice sends "Pay Bob $100", you don't want somebody to re-send that 100 times).

CSRF tokens patch HTML-specific weakness in authentication of users' action, where 3rd party website can submit forms with credentials of user viewing the site (e.g. JavaScript on evil.example.com submitting form to facebook.com using your browser, authenticated as you).

CSRF tokens need to be secret, otherwise attacker would have the missing piece required to forge a request.

Nonces don't have to be secret if they're signed with requester's secret (as long as attacker cannot replace one nonce with another).

You can allow replay of requests with CSRF tokens and still be secured against CSRF (you're interested whether that was intentional action by the user, but may not necessarily want to stop user from performing it many times).

In fact, that's very often useful property, e.g. allows users to use Back button and re-submit forms with corrected values. If you implement CSRF protection with Nonce-like mechanism, you'll get false alarms when users refresh submitted pages.

An easy way to prevent CSRF without Nonces is to put session ID in a hidden from field (not a value stored *in* the session, but ID of the session itself, the same that you store in the cookie [`session_id()` in PHP]). When the form is submitted check that form's session ID matches ID in the cookie. That is enough for CSRF, since attacker cannot know *value* of the cookie (CSRF only allows attackers to blindly send cookies).

Comment: You shouldn't use an identifier (like a session ID) as a CSRF token, this allows the attacker to trick the victim by, for example, asking to get the page Saved as HTML, with a still valid session ID embedded.

Answer (score 10):

It's sort of the same thing. A "nonce" is just a one-time password itself. It can serve as cryptographic salt, but basically is just a random value. See [WP:Nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)

But to sum it up, a nonce is often used ***as*** CSRF token. It's an implementation detail. The difference to other use cases is that it later gets asserted.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF having some limitation.
in case if  you have requirement where you want to open any page or link in new tab then CSRF won't allow. existing token will allow to open page in new tab for 5 times only.
when you will try to open 6th time it will create the new token which will not match with "server side = client side token". earlier token will expire and new token(NONCE) will create, in that case you will get 404 or 405 error.