# Preventing CSRF by generating a nonce token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, token, csrf, nonce

I was reading [This article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-5.html) about preventing CSRF by creating a nonce token which going to be sent as variable in ajax function along with a session hold the same value as in the token. Is this a good idea because I realy don't like the useing of sessions specially with big website which has many active users all the time , which going to affect the general performance ?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?  If so, you can just use the AntiForgeryToken mentioned here http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/29/AntiForgeryTokenInMVCFramework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, nonce is not necessary as long as you'll have unique, unguessable value for each user. It could be for example `SHA1( user_id + "secret string nobody knows")`.

I've replied about difference between nonces and CSRF in another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9803497/27009