# Easiest way to create a unique code to use between Javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, php-5.6

I'm looking for a way to create the same code in both JavaScript and PHP as a security measure to make sure you can't just access the PHP script, but only when this JavaScript says to access it.

I am using AJAX to access a PHP logging file

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('POST', 'log/', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send('uniqueCode=xxxxxxxx...');
```

(where `xxxxxxxx...` is the unique code.)

In the PHP code I want to add

```
if ($_POST['uniqueCode'] === xxxxxxxx...) {
    //Run Code
}else {
    http_response_code(403);
}
```

(where `xxxxxxxx...` is the unique code.)

Is there a way to transfer this unique code beforehand and then use the above code?

I am using PHP Version 5.6

Comment: You do know that anyone can capture that unique code and just send the unique code using any other tool? What you call a security measurement isn't one. It can be manipulated and interfered at any time. Looks like a XY problem to me. What problem are you trying to solve by that?

Comment: You use PHP to embed the ID in the JavaScript. There is no way JavaScript that has no knowledge of the PHP process can magically create the same random ID.

Comment: This would be a horrible security "feature". You can't hide the source of the javascript run to create the matching "token". Meaning anyone can just copy it, re-create it in any other language out there, and access your script whenever they want by just generating whatever the token should be at that time. If you want to time-limit a script in PHP, just store when they can access the page in a php session. Then on any request, if the current time isn't past that stored time, throw an error and send back a "too soon" message.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois the PHP script writes a lot of information to the server, and I am just trying to prevent any sort of DDOS.  This key will be used one time, and will expire.  This is how YouTube videos are saved, in 2 playlist files, one with the video and the other with audio, both of the playlist files *and* all the video/audio files use this key which expires after a few minutes.  This is why you need a program, or the new YouTube Red, to download the videos and you cannot just right click and save.

Comment: DDoS just floods the server with requests, it doesn't care if you actually let the script do what the user requested or not. What you are most likely looking for is CSRF Token. Read about CSRF (Cross-Site-Request-Forgery) on Wikipedia if you don't know much about it yet.

Comment: In the case of a system like that, the server is still likely generating all the tokens. Which could mean the client side is making an ajax request to the server to generate the token or the server is outputting the token to the source of the page for the javascript to use. Once the javascript has the token, it supplies it for future requests.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for CSRF validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that an end user has some sort of authority to do something, you need to use sessions. For better security, you need to use https instead of http. That makes it far more difficult to steal the session key. Stealing a random code from JavaScript is trivial compared to stealing a session key.

Doing this is very simple...

```
<?php
start_session();
if($_SESSION['authorized']) // the user can do the secret stuff
else // the user cannot do the secret stuff
```

Setting the user to be authorized is just as simple...

```
$_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
```

That's all there is to it. Once you start a session, the variables in the $_SESSION array are, as best as you get it, tied to the end user.

Answer (score -1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691492/csrf-tokens-vs-nonce-confusion-are-they-the-same) you can use this function

```
md5(uniqid('', true));
```

If possible, please specify the PHP ver, so we ca check on the manual for newer solutions :)

Comment: PHP Version 5.6, I will add this to my question as well.

Comment: Look at the "session CSRF token" and "nonce" from the question I linked

Comment: I wouldn't use `md5(uniqid('', true));` since that is predictable. Instead get a pseudorandom value from something like `mt_rand()`.

Comment: @Mike He should rather use OpenSSL. http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Comment: I wouldn't use `mt_rand()` either. `random_bytes()` for PHP 7 and [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) for PHP 5 are the canon solutions here.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Thanks. I didn't know about that function.

Comment: @PietroLerro I've amended the answer you linked to to suggest better security practices. You may wish to revise any code you've used that one-liner in and migrate to `random_bytes()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottArciszewski, I'll check my code :)